# Exception when trying to iterate LinkedHashMap

Tags: android

I have a `LinkedHashMap` which contains string keys and `ArrayList` values. When I try to iterate over it, I get an exception stating "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList" Code:

```
 Iterator it = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
 while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    String key = (String)entry.getKey();
    ArrayList maps = (ArrayList)entry.getValue();
}
```

How can I iterate without an exception?

Comment: What is the type of `v` in `Map<K,V>` ? Probably its `String` !

Comment: entry.getValue() returns a String, not an ArrayList. The contents of your hashMap are not what you think they are.

Comment: Post declaration of `hashMap` and stop having us guessing and suspecting...

Comment: @m0skit0 The question clearly states the contents.

Comment: Who is talking about contents? *[Declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_%28computer_programming%29)* has nothing to do with contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't keySet() work faster? This might be more accurate, but off the top of my head...

```
Iterator it = hashMap.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
     String key = (String)it.next();
     ArrayList maps = (ArrayList)hashMap.get(key);
}
```

Comment: You're right but this is unrelated to the question. And this is a suggestion not an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of this.

Comment: @RunLoop so this answers your question? Awesome. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Given the code in the question and the exception that was thrown, it's impossible that this solves that exception, even if this answer was accepted. The problem was somewhere else. Just leaving this comment as a warning for people that find this question later.